# Identity 2.0 After Login go to Infinite Loop asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I have added email confirmation process like below:

```
 var code = await _users.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(model.UserName);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action(
               "ConfirmEmail", "Account",
               new { username = model.UserName, code = code },
               protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

then confirm email with below code:

```
public async Task ConfirmationEmailAsync(CmsUser user, string token)
    {
        var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"].ToString());
        _manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<CmsUser>(
        provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));

        await _manager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user.Id, token);
    }
```

after that I will login it will go to infinite loop.

http://localhost:3214/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Faccount%2Flogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252Faccount%252Flogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252Faccount%25252Flogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252Faccount%2525252Flogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252Faccount%252525252Flogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252Faccount%25252525252Flogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252Faccount%2525252525252Flogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252Faccount%252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525...

Here, I have calling below method:

```
 public async Task<string> GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(CmsUser user)
    {
        var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"].ToString());
        _manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<CmsUser>(
        provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));

        return await _manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about your Generate EMail action. It is about your authentication.

Probably, your `Login` action in `Account` controller is requiring authorization.  For instance, you can have `AuthorizeAttribute` on an action or a controller. Maybe, it's a global filter or something's wrong with Web.config.

Anyway, that's what actually happens:

1. User tries to access your Generate EMail method
2. He is unauthorized. Then, he is redirected to `Account` / `Login` method.
3. This method requires authorization. Goto 2.

You need to review your authentication, debug it and find the basic problem before you continue implementing your EMail confirmation.